# Select2 additional checkbox not checking

Tags: jquery-select2

Hei guys.

I'm trying to add additional HTML elements below search box.. like checkboxes for filtering purposes.
But the added checkbox is not functional, you can't actually check it. I'm not sure but I think that search box is taking the focus from them... I created this jsFiddle so you guys can check it out.

http://jsfiddle.net/6wz2hLh0/

```
$("#e1").select2();
//Inserting additional HTML elements below search... filter in my case
$(".select2-search").after("<input type='checkbox'/>");
```

When the dropdown is open you can't even write in jsFiddle input's.

I tried commenting out various focus calls from source code with no luck.

Can any one point me in to right direction in source code what is causing this non stop search box focussing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing to try is to have the checkbox element stop the mouse events from propagating. That seems to prevent them from getting to Select2, so Select2 cannot kill them.

```
$("<input type='checkbox'/>")
    .insertAfter(".select2-search")
    .on('mousedown mouseup click', function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); });
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lyayfaxd/1/)

Comment: Both solutions would work but this one doesn't require changing Select2 source code.. Accepting this one.

Comment: And how to trigger search when checking on the checkbox?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not sure but I think that search box is taking the focus from them

My guess is that this is because Select2 kills (stops propagation and prevents default) most events that occur within the dropdown. This is so Select2 doesn't leak events, but it also causes problems like not being able to catch `click` events or embed links.

> When the dropdown is open you can't even write in jsFiddle input's.

This is because Select2 uses a mask that captures all events outside of the dropdown.

> Can any one point me in to right direction in source code what is causing this non stop search box focussing.

You are going to want to look through the source for `killEvent`, as this is the method Select2 uses that kills events. As most browsers listen for the `click` event for native controls, you probably want to remove [this `killEvent` for dropdown clicks](https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2/blob/39394e2ee804f2f2bfc900eaba6060130d2681b2/select2.js#L745).