# select2 cursor focus not jump

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I inserted an input text on my select2:

```
$("#selectBank").select2("container").find("div.select2-drop").append('<div><input type="text" class="inputADD" role="comboboxadd" id="addBank" placeholder=""><input type="submit" value="Add"></div>');
```

it happens that the **cursor focus** is all the time in the input searchbox select2 .. when I click on my new input text the cursor focus not jump to my new field.

link of the example (sorry i not have 10 reputation, i´m newbie to post it):
http://s2.postimg.org/9vw90oze1/SL1.png

Any solution?

Comment: I found a similar topic (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27185950/select2-additional-checkbox-not-checking) but did not work with the input text =/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
`$('<div><input type="text" class="inputADD" role="comboboxadd" id="addBank" placeholder=""><input type="submit" value="Add"></div>').insertAfter("#s2id_singleSelectExample .select2-results").on('mousedown mouseup click', 

    function(e) { 
        $( "#s2id_autogen1_search" ).prop( "disabled", true );
    $('#s2id_autogen1_search').css('cursor','text');

        }
).on('focusout', 
    function(e) { 
        $( "#s2id_autogen1_search" ).prop( "disabled", false );
    });
```

Comment: I'm glad my friend ;)